# How do we display the page content in a metro app as if it is shown in the web page?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a .html file in my Modern Win8 app project which has a web page data .Now How do we display the page content in this modern app as if it is shown in the web page ?

Note: I dont want to navigaet away from the app.Within app i want to show the content from the .html file i saved in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227702.aspx) Object and navigate to the page locally in the project folder.

ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html

Comment: I have added a control as specified im the above link.i.e.                                                                     <WebView   Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html"/>                                               But it doesn't display the data though there is no error.Anything else i am missing.

Comment: It might be a malformed URL, check it over and see that all the folder paths are correct.

Comment: WebView1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible; has solved the problem.

Comment: How do we assign the same source(that is a htmlpage1.html file from project folder ) at run time ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) control and set as source the file you saved in your project.

```
<WebView Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html"/>
```